# How do I put a multi color border around my circular image?

Tags: html, css

I need to put a multi-colored border around my circular image. [example borders](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PuIY-Zl9soWGw7m5uVV_XYOUcn7mjQw_/view)

I have tried various guides online but I can't seem to get the hang of it.

I tried to use linear-gradient but I ended up with 4 dots in the corner as if the image was square, no border was present.

```css
.img-border1 {
  border: 6px solid #e42c64;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-border2 {
  border: 6px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red 33.33%, blue 33.33%, yellow 33.33%);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <img class="img-res img-border1 rounded-circle" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" alt="simon-game" width="140" height="140">
  <h2>My Simon Game</h2>
  <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://rbas30.github.io/simon-game/" role="button">Play the game »</a></p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <img class="img-res img-border2 rounded-circle" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" alt="simon-game" width="140" height="140">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you maybe have an image of how should it (this image with images ) look if it is done successfully?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code for your attempts. While we can certainly answer this for you, you need to show what you've done. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes the link does that I believe so, let me know if I misunderstood your question @Lelo

Comment: @R.Sykes - How does your current image look? where is it's code showing it's position and it's current border?

Comment: @ disinfor thank you for clearing that up and the useful link, @Lelo I wish I could upload an image it would be easier, but essentially I have a round image it is 140px both height and width. I want to put a border around this image that has 50% one color 50% another color. Then on another image, same size, I want a border that is 33.33% for three different colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using a little more markup and `pseudo` elements:

```css
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.image-wrap-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.image-wrap img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
}

.img-border-two::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 70px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.img-border-three::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  background: purple;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: matrix(2, 1, 2, -1, 0, 140);
}

.img-border-three::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 70px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="image-wrap img-border-two">
    <div class="image-wrap-inner">
      <img class="img-res rounded-circle" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" alt="simon-game" width="140" height="140">
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="image-wrap img-border-three">
    <div class="image-wrap-inner">
      <img class="img-res rounded-circle" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" alt="simon-game" width="140" height="140">
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
</div>
```

Caveats:

1. This isn't responsive, so your images will always be 140px x 140px.
2. If you adjust the width/height of the image or the `padding` on `.image-wrap`, you also need to change the `.image-wrap-inner` `width` and `height` to account for the padding/size change.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will implement the code later after I look at it a bit and try to figure out how it works. Also, how hard would it be to make it responsive? Is this something that I could achieve through a little research or is it another monster in itself?

Comment: It might take a bit to get it responsive, but it can be done. Do you plan on having the images getting larger than 140px? Smaller?

Comment: Possible larger, but if it might take a bit I'll just accept this answer for now. I'm still not too comfortable with how "::before" and "::after" work so i should probably figure that out first, thank you for the response!

Comment: Cool. You can mark it as accepted and if you have more questions, ask away and I can update the answer. `::before` and `::after` are really just "fake" elements that you can append to another element. Super fun.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet which is based on [this pen](https://codepen.io/hilar47/pen/RprXev): You can comment out none needed animation from styles.

```css
.img-border1 {
  border: 6px solid #e42c64;
}

.img-border2 { 
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}

 /* donut-chart (h x w) should be 15px larger than image to prevent white overflow */
.donut-chart {
  position: relative;
 width: 165px;
  height: 165px;
 border-radius: 100%
 }
img.center {
  background: #394264;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center; 
  top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 
 
.portion-block {
    border-radius: 50%;
    clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  }
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: monospace;
  }
 
 /* Image 1 */
#Img1part1 {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  } 
 #Img1part1 .circle {
  background-color: #00e0ff;
  /*transform: rotate(76deg);*/
  animation: first 1s 1 forwards;
   } 
#Img1part2 {
    transform: rotate(100deg);
  }
#Img1part2 .circle {
    background-color: #e20075;
    animation: second 1s 1 forwards 1s;
  }
#Img1part3 {
    transform: rotate(250deg);
}
 #Img1part3 .circle {
  background-color: #41cf74;
  animation: third 0.5s 1 forwards 2s;
 }
  #Img1part3 .circle {
  background-color: #41cf74;
  animation: third 0.5s 1 forwards 2s;
 }
  
  
 /* Image 2 */
  #Img2part1 {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  } 
 #Img2part1 .circle {
  background-color: #0023ff;
  /*transform: rotate(76deg);*/
  animation: first 1s 1 forwards;
   } 
#Img2part2 {
    transform: rotate(100deg);
  }
#Img2part2 .circle {
    background-color: #fff075;
    animation: second 1s 1 forwards 1s;
  }
#Img2part3 {
    transform: rotate(250deg);
}
 #Img2part3 .circle {
  background-color: #41cf74;
  animation: third 0.5s 1 forwards 2s;
 }
  #Img2part3 .circle {
  background-color: #41cf74;
  animation: third 0.5s 1 forwards 2s;
 }
 
 
/* Sample Animation */
@keyframes first {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(100deg);}
}
 
@keyframes second {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(150deg);}
}
 
@keyframes third {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(111deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 ">
<div class="donut-chart">
   <div id="Img1part1" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
   <div id="Img1part2" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
   <div id="Img1part3" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <img class="img-res img-border2 rounded-circle center" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" alt="simon-game" width="140" height="140">
  </div>
  <h2>My Simon Game</h2>
  <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://rbas30.github.io/simon-game/" role="button">Play the game »</a></p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="donut-chart">
   <div id="Img2part1" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
   <div id="Img2part2" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
   <div id="Img2part3" class="portion-block"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <img class="img-res img-border2 rounded-circle center" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" alt="simon-game" width="140" height="140">      
  </div>
  
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just used a little hack here, I have used your code, in it instead of giving gradient background to image tag I have to give it to parent div.

```css
.img-border2 {
 width:140px;
  height:140px;
  border-width:4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue,yellow);
  padding :6px;

}
.img-border2 img{ border-radius:50%;}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="img-border2">
  <img class="img-res  rounded-circle" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" alt="simon-game">
  </div>
 </div>
```